# How do I use a specific view in Power Apps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, powerapp

Arguably this is a PowerApps question as well, but I thought my SharePoint folks might have encountered this one.

I am showing a SharePoint list in a PowerApp, let's call it 'Upcoming Events' and Power Apps brings in the data, but it looks like it pulls all items.

Is there a way to pull a particular view with the correct REST url?

I am using SharePoint Online and Power Apps to create a simple interface for my users.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use the [custom connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/) to connect to the SharePoint REST API, though that's certainly not a trivial process, nor is this specific scenario documented that I'm aware of. Another possibility to use create a custom azure function that returns the data you need, and call that from Power Apps. The easier way is to use the filter function within PowerApps to get the data you need, no coding required. While creating the logic for the filter, you'd need to replicate the logic of the view, but that would most likely take less time than the other options, and would look something like this:

```
Gallery1.Items = Sort(Filter('data source name',field1 = "some value"),Modified,Descending)
```

Comment: I know about `Filter` and `SortByColumn` however those operate on the data after you retrieve the first N rows from SharePoint.  I want to get a pre-filter pre-sorted view from SharePoint. I use custom connectors for other things but that seems like overkill for this

Comment: Filter is deletable from SharePoint, depending on the operators used. So it should return the first n records that meet the condition.

Comment: Delegable, not deletable. Sorry.

Comment: I'll inspect.  but my goal is not to re-implement my view(s) logic in PowerApps.  Proxy through an ASP.NET Web API / Custom Connector will to be the band-aid solution for now.  I'm pretty sure there is a "Custom SharePoint API request" action somewhere.